# How to use pg-service.conf service as dblink connection string in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I have pg_service.conf file with following config

### pg_service.conf

```
[test-service]
host=localhost
port=5432
user=test-user
password=*****
dbname=test-table
```

While running following query shows error

### Query

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM                                                                                                      
  DBLINK('service=test-service',
    'SELECT id, name FROM student' 
  ) AS sq0(id int, name text) order by 1;
```

### ERROR

```
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  definition of service "test-service" not found
```

Comment: try `SELECT id, name 
FROM                                                                                                      
  DBLINK('server=test-localhost port=5432 user=test-user password=*** dbname=dbname ',
    'SELECT id, name FROM student' 
  ) AS sq0(id int, name text) order by 1;`

Comment: if i give connection string ('server=test-localhost port=5432 user=test-user password=*** dbname=dbname ') directly it's working fine. But I want to use that service name(test-service) instead of connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define `PGSERVICEFILE` and `PGSERVICE` environment variables? If not please define those in the environment file as follows,

```
export PGSERVICEFILE=${HOME}/.pg_service.conf   # location to the .pg_service.conf file
export PGSERVICE=test-service
```

If you going to use multiple schema, you can use `.pg_service.conf` to define db name, ip and port and `.pgpass` file to define user names and passwords. Please not that `.pgpass` should be in your home folder. Also above variables should be set.

**Sample .pg_service.conf**

```
[test-service]
host=localhost
port=5432
dbname=test-table
```

**Sample .pgpass**

```
localhost:5432:test-table:test-user1:******
localhost:5432:test-table:test-user2:******
```

Then you can execute the query from the terminal by, `psql --user=test-user1 -c "query"`